# Crossed and nested factors in Negative Binomial Model

Tags: mixed-model, count-data, zero-inflation

I am unsure as to whether I have set up the following mixed model correctly.

The following are fictional data but illustrate the problem accurately.

- We have 32 unique subjects (a1 - a32).
- Each subject belongs to one of 4 families (A,B,C,D)
- There are 8 subjects in each family.
- We take two measurements of our outcome variable (value) for each subject (before & after).
- Each subject could belong to one of two conditions (control vs treatment)
- Each family has 4 subjects in control and 4 subjects in treatment.
- The data have a lot of zeros as the measured variable can often be 0.
- Each subject in each family has their outcome variable (value) measured in order (= measure - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, or 8).

Raw Data:

```r
demodf=structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 23L, 23L, 27L, 
27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
25L, 26L, 26L), .Label = c("a1", "a10", "a11", "a12", "a13", 
"a14", "a15", "a16", "a17", "a18", "a19", "a2", "a20", "a21", 
"a22", "a23", "a24", "a25", "a26", "a27", "a28", "a29", "a3", 
"a30", "a31", "a32", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("before", 
    "after"), class = "factor"), family = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("control", 
    "treatment"), class = "factor"), value = c(6L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 
    9L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
    0L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 11L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 
    5L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L), measure = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 
    8, 8, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 2, 
    2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 2, 2, 4, 4, 
    6, 6, 8, 8, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7)), .Names = c("id", "time", 
"family", "group", "value", "measure"), row.names = c(NA, -64L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Here are some summary ways of looking at the data:

```r
table(demodf$group,demodf$family,demodf$time)
, ,  = before

           
            A B C D
  control   4 4 4 4
  treatment 4 4 4 4

, ,  = after

           
            A B C D
  control   4 4 4 4
  treatment 4 4 4 4



table(demodf$group,demodf$family,demodf$measure)
, ,  = 1

           
            A B C D
  control   0 2 0 2
  treatment 2 0 2 0

, ,  = 2

           
            A B C D
  control   2 0 2 0
  treatment 0 2 0 2

, ,  = 3

           
            A B C D
  control   0 2 0 2
  treatment 2 0 2 0

, ,  = 4

           
            A B C D
  control   2 0 2 0
  treatment 0 2 0 2

, ,  = 5

           
            A B C D
  control   0 2 0 2
  treatment 2 0 2 0

, ,  = 6

           
            A B C D
  control   2 0 2 0
  treatment 0 2 0 2

, ,  = 7

           
            A B C D
  control   0 2 0 2
  treatment 2 0 2 0

, ,  = 8

           
            A B C D
  control   2 0 2 0
  treatment 0 2 0 2
```

These are summaries of the top and bottom of the raw data:

```r
head(demodf)
  id   time family     group value measure
1 a1  after      A treatment     6       1
2 a1 before      A treatment     0       1
3 a2  after      A treatment     7       3
4 a2 before      A treatment     5       3
5 a3  after      A treatment     9       5
6 a3 before      A treatment     6       5


tail(demodf)
    id   time family   group value measure
59 a30  after      D control     2       3
60 a30 before      D control     0       3
61 a31  after      D control     4       5
62 a31 before      D control     1       5
63 a32  after      D control     0       7
64 a32 before      D control     0       7
```

A histogram of the measured 'value':

[image]

This is a plot of the raw data, looking at value by subject across time and family:

[image]

I believe that the most appropriate mixed model would be a zero-inflated negative binomial model.  I have tried implementing this in R using `glmmADMB` using an interaction between `time*group` to test whether those in the 'treatment' group do show higher levels of 'value' after compared to before.  I want to account for the crossed-factors 'family' and 'measure'(order of testing) so have added those as random factors.

```r
library(glmmADMB)
fit <- glmmadmb(value ~ group*time, data=demodf, 
                random = ~ (1 | family) + (1 | measure), 
                zeroInflation = TRUE, family = "nbinom")
```

I am not 100% sure this is an appropriate model.  Particularly, id is nested in family and measure.  Should I be using `1|family/id` or `1|measure/id` ?  When I try that the model gives an error.   My major question is whether I should be accounting for 'id' in the model, or if it is already accounted for?